# Find to substring and its index in the List

Tags: python, string, list

I couldn't solve a problem regarding to substring operations in index. Let me try to explain..

I have a answer list and I need to catch first "No" answer. After that I'll use the this first "No" answer's ID. For example;

```
list = ["Yes: 0.5", "Yes: 1.0", "Yes: 1.5", "Yes: 2.0", "No: 2.5", "No: 3.0"]
```

I have 5 result in my list and I have to find which question's result = "No"..

If I can success to catch first "No" answer and its index, I can access the others informations..

In that case, I need to catch first "No: 2.5" it means index no=4..

When I tried that, I couldn't catch first "No" answer. How can I do that?

Comment: `index = next(i for i, v in enumerate(list) if v.startswith('No'))`

Comment: index_list = [list.index(i) for i in list if "No".lower() in i.lower()]

Comment: @Veeresh `"No".lower()`…?!

Comment: @deceze Not to miss if any of the string contains lowercase of "no".

Comment: @Veeresh You could just write `'no'` instead of `"No".lower()`…

Comment: @deceze Yes I got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
d =  ["Yes: 0.5", "Yes: 1.0", "Yes: 1.5", "Yes: 2.0", "No: 2.5", "No: 3.0"]
d.index([x for x in d if 'No' in x][0])

# 4
```

This is not best for performance but does the job if your list is short.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's ok for me!